# Good article on sockets?

Tags: sockets, networking

I was just wondering where I could find a article on sockets. I don't want any indepth code. I just want to understand the structures and other stuff like the how the buffers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) pretty informative.